# Searching for a connected neighborhood of fixed radius for every point of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $\Gamma=\gamma(\partial D)\subset \mathbb R^3$ be an image of $C^1$-curve, where $D$ is an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$.
My question is whether it is possible to find a fixed $\epsilon >0$ such that for every point $p \in \Gamma$ the neighborhood $$B_\epsilon(p) \cap \Gamma$$ is connected in space $\Gamma$. $B_\epsilon(p)$ denotes open ball of radius $\epsilon$ in $\mathbb R^3$.
I thought since $\Gamma$ can be considered as $C^1$-manifold of $\mathbb R^3$ some neighborhood of every point $p$ can be approximated (i.e. diffeomorphic) to tangent line. Now repeat procedure for every point, take smallest and we get desired $\epsilon$.
But how to assure no pathologies like $\sin(1/x)$ can occure? In this case I would get $\epsilon = 0$.

Edit: As @MoisheCohen  pointed out we have to assume that

- $\Gamma$ is a compact 1 dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ i.e. exists $\gamma: S^1 \to \mathbb R^3 $ regular smooth injective map such that $\gamma(S^1)=\Gamma$.

Comment: Your question is poorly phrased and it is unlikely you will get a reasonable answer. If all you assume is that your set is the image of $S^1$ under a $C^1$-map then what you are trying to prove is false. You need to assume that you have a compact $C^1$-smooth submanifold, e.g. the image of $S^1$ under a regular $C^1$-smooth injective map. Regularity means that the derivative is nowhere zero.

Comment: @MoisheCohen thank you for pointing out, I edited my post. Do you mind explaining what the difference is between $C^1$-smooth and $C^1$-submanifold? Also why do we require regularity property, isn't local homeorphism sufficient? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first prove that for any point $p \in \Gamma$ there exists an $\bar{\epsilon} = \bar{\epsilon}(p) > 0$ (which depends on $p$) such that $B_{\epsilon}(p) \cap \Gamma$ is connected for every $0 < \epsilon \le \bar{\epsilon}$.

Now observe that $\{B_{\epsilon}(p) \cap \Gamma  \colon  0 < \epsilon < \bar{\epsilon}(p)\}$ is an open cover of $\Gamma$. Then the conclusion follows from the compactness of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Thank you! Although I might need your help to finish the proof. As you mentioned $\Gamma = \cup _ {p \in \Gamma} \{B_{\epsilon}(p) \cap \Gamma  \colon  0 < \epsilon < \bar{\epsilon}(p)\}$. From compactness we get finitely many points $p_1,...,p_n \in \Gamma$ corresponding to your cover. Let $q \in \Gamma$ arbitrary, then $q$ is in $B_\epsilon(p_i) \cap \Gamma$ for some $\epsilon: 0<\epsilon<\bar \epsilon(p_i)$. Which fixed $\epsilon$ that is indepent on $q$ should I take? Sorry for being that ignorant.

Comment: What happens if you try to take $\min\{\bar\epsilon(p_i): 1\le i\le n\}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin sure, let's take $\epsilon_m$ as you noted. Then in order to $B_{\epsilon_m}(q)\cap \Gamma$ to be connected it, we can show, $\epsilon_m \leq \bar \epsilon(q)$. Which is not quite clear to me... Please give me a hint, I feel embarassed. Also, Ted, have to say, your notes on differential geometry are awesome, helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $B(x, \epsilon)\bigcap \Gamma$ is not
connected for $x\in \Gamma$.

Hence there is at least four points in $\partial B(x,\epsilon
)\bigcap \Gamma $, i.e. $x_i$ where $x_1,\ x_2$ are connected in the
ball and so are $x_3,\ x_4$.

Here there is $x_{12}$ in the arc between $x_1$ and $x_2$ whose
tangent line $T_{12}$ is close to a line containing segment
$[x_1x_2]$.

Consider a sequence of points $a_n\in \Gamma$ converging to $a$ s.t.
$B(a_n,1/n)\bigcap \Gamma$ is not connected.

Here $T_{12}(a_n),\ T_{34}(a_n)$ have different limits so that it is
not $C^1$.

If they have same limits and $x_2,\ x_3$ are connected, then there
is a point $x_{23}$ whose tangent line $T_{23}(a_n)$ is close to a
line containing $[x_2x_3]$. Hence $T_{12}(a_n),\ T_{23}(a_n)$ have
different limits.

Comment: OP is asking for a compact subset (continuous, in fact, $C^1$, image of the circle).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified my answer.